# CakePHP unit testing

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, phpunit

I am new to php unit testing and every time I try to learn something it doesn't work as the cakephp documentation

1- Starting with the fixtures : I ran the command  `bin/cake bake fixture tablename` and tried to execute the test (which is basically empty) : The table gets deleted from the database (I read that its a normal behavior but its not re-created, I should create It everytimee?)

2- I now want to try how it actually work in the test controller and added a basic function and ran the test to this specific controller. I get the error :

```
Use of undefined constant CONFIG - assumed 'CONFIG' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Router.php:1170
```

How can I fix all this ?

Comment: I think, answer to this question is following the right approach. I suggest you read : https://jtreminio.com/blog/unit-testing-tutorial-part-i-introduction-to-phpunit/

Comment: For 1, you should a different database (empty database is okay) because when starting the test, it will create and insert the data from the fixture. After the test it will clean it up. So no need to create  everytime.